# Почему sayi1 принемает значение sayi2?

Tags: c#

sayi1 принемает значения sayi2 не могу понять почему. Вроде бы 
sayi2 = sayi1 то есть в sayi2 перекидываются значения sayi1 но потом когда sayi2 = 5 и это же значение присваевается и к sayi1.
ответ этой программы 
5 5
6 7

```
class Sayi
{
    public int Deger { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sayi sayi1 = new Sayi();
        sayi1.Deger = 4;
        Sayi sayi2 = sayi1;
        sayi2.Deger = 5;
        int sayi3 = new int();
        sayi3 = 6;
        int sayi4 = sayi3;
        sayi4 = 7;
        Console.WriteLine(sayi1.Deger + “ ” +sayi2.Deger);
        Console.WriteLine(sayi3 +“ ” +sayi4);
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что класс - это ссылочный тип, а int - нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# существуют две разновидности типов: ссылочные типы и типы значений. В переменных ссылочных типов хранятся ссылки на их данные (объекты), а переменные типа значений содержат свои данные непосредственно. Две переменные ссылочного типа могут ссылаться на один и тот же объект, поэтому операции над одной переменной могут затрагивать объект, на который ссылается другая переменная. Каждая переменная типа значения имеет собственную копию данных, и операции над одной переменной не могут затрагивать другую (за исключением переменных параметров out и ref, см. разделы ref и Модификатор параметров out).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/490f96s2.aspx

Происходит создание ссылки sayi2 на sayi1. Они ведут на одни и те же данные.

```
Sayi sayi2 = sayi1;
```

Для того чтобы создать несвязанную копию нужно использовать `new`

```
Sayi sayi2 = new Sayi(sayi1);
```

int не является ссылочным типом.

```
int sayi4 = sayi3;
```